# Why equals() in String is faster than equals() in char array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, comparison

Now I am facing a problem in Java that needs to compare two char array. I firstly used statement like (array1.equals(array2)) and it returns the result very slow. Then I found if I used statement like(new String(array1).equals(new String(array2)), it surprisingly became much faster. Later I also found if I use equals() function in Array class, then the speed is also much faster than directly calling equals() on array1. So why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistaken.

```
array1.equals(array2)
```

will simply do `array1 == array2` and will always return false if `array1` and `array2` references don't point to same array instance. So this should be pretty quick as it's just memory location matching.

If you see `equals()` in String class it is

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
if (this == anObject) {
    return true;
}
if (anObject instanceof String) {
    String anotherString = (String)anObject;
    int n = count;
    if (n == anotherString.count) {
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;
    int i = offset;
    int j = anotherString.offset;
    while (n-- != 0) {
        if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

where as that of Arrays class is

```
public static boolean equals(long[] a, long[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (a[i] != a2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

You can use any one of the above. All you are doing is converting your char array to String and equals in String again uses the char array in the String internal representation to compare. More or less both methods have same time complexity.

But yes in your case you should use `Arrays.equals()` for best performance and result.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking at is some thing like this.

```
public class CharComparison {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] array1 = "some random string".toCharArray();
        char[] array2 = "other random string".toCharArray();

        System.out.println(array1.equals(array2));// object class == comparison

        System.out.println(new String(array1).equals(new String(array2))); // String equals comparison

        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(array1,array2)); // Arrays.equals(foo,bar) comparison
    }
}
```

The first way of comparison should be the fastest, since it is just looking at the object reference equality. The other two implementations having the same time complexity as the other answer mentioned.